# Using an Array Items Property Value to display in UITableView/UICollectionView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I know how to use an array to display in a `UItableView` or `UICollectionView` but unsure how to specify the data.

So instead of simply displaying all items in the array, to filter the results using a items property value. For for e.g each item in the array has a property called number, if the number is 2 then display, `products[indexPath.row].number == 2` if the `.number == 1` then don't.

In my application I have a fetch request which I create an array to display in a collectionView. Each `Product` has a property called `number`, but how do I display products with a *number equal to 2* ?

**Fetch Request:**

```
var products = [Product]()

func loadData() {

    var error: NSError?

    let moc1 = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let request1 = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Product")
    request1.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    self.products = moc1?.executeFetchRequest(request1, error: &error) as! [Product]

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**CollectionView:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return products.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.products[indexPath.row].title

    return cell

}
```

Comment: Filter `products` once you fetched the data (remove the ones with .numbers != 2). There are plenty of question in SO about filtering array with custom object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's say you got your array of products:

```
let products =  [
                    [ "name" : "t-shirt", "number" : 3 ],
                    [ "name" : "shirt", "number" : 1 ],
                    [ "name" : "shorts", "number" : 2 ],
                    [ "name" : "top", "number" : 2 ]
                ]
```

Then you can simply filter the array using Swift's `filter` function like this:

```
let filteredProducts = products.filter({ product in
    product["number"] == 2
})
```

Or even shorter:

```
let filteredProducts = products.filter{$0["number"] == 2}
```

`filteredProducts` will then contain every `product` with `number = 2`. You can then use that array for your `UICollectionView` or simply just override your existing `products` variable.

I don't know the details about your `Products` object, but you probably want to do something like:

```
let filteredProducts = products.filter{$0.number == 2}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to iOS development and overlooked the filter method. A filter method using a closure is nice a clean.